# How to decompose Word document for easy pasting into Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I analyze documents and would like to be able to highlight a Word document and have the paragraph sentences separate into separate lines.  This would ease having a complete document decomposed to enable Excel analysis.  Would anyone please suggest a way to enable me to "shred" a document into a line by line format?  Thank you.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more about what you are trying to achieve? Is this a task that you currently do manually? Are you saying that you would like to take a .docx and extract each *line* or each *sentence* out?

Answer (score 0):

You could exchange all dots with semicolon (if I understood right you want to go by sentence).
Then you copy the content to notepad and save it as pure text file with the extension .csv.
That file you can open via excel and you will have seperate columns for each semicolon set, it might be that you have to specify what is interpreted as new column. You may have to transpose of you want rows instead of columns.
[I'll add some screen shots as soon as I can]

Comment: Thank you both for your responses.  Let me elaborate on what I'd like to do.  In my business, I deal with RFP's (Requests for Proposals).  The RFP is often in .pdf format.  What I want to do is to copy the .pdf, and be able to paste it into Excel in a "shred" - so every sentence is "shred" into  individual sentences into separate rows of an Excel spreadsheet.  This enables analysis of the RFP, and the construction of a Matrix to enable tracking of the Proposal in response to the RFP.

Comment: Also, I have seen the Adobe service that converts .pdf's into Excel and that may be an approach that I'll have to use at $19.99 I think each conversion.  I have tried to copy the .pdf into Word and then manually manipulate the conversion so I can copy/paste into Excel - but that takes a lot of time I'd much rather spend on analysis and progress.  I will look into the .csv approach - I like the approach.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @D.Ryan Could you please "elaborate on what you'd like to do" in your question? You can edit it and add that information. If you want people to answer your problem, don't force them to read all your scattered comments.

Answer (score 0):

can you elaborate a bit more on the request, as I understand you want to be able to highlight a text on word and this text copy/paste on excel to analyze it but each sentence of the highlighted text on a cell for each one on excel? if that's what you want follow this steps:

1. Select the text you want on the word doc and to select all non-contiguous highlighted sections in a document, press “Ctrl + H” to open the “Find and Replace” dialog box. Click the “Find” tab.

   2.Click the “More” button to expand the FIND dialog box and view more options.
   [More Options on FIND][2]
2. Click the “Format” button and select “Highlight” from the popup menu.

   4. The “Highlight” format is listed under the “Find what” edit box. Click “Find In” and select “Main Document” from the popup menu.
      [Find what and where][1]
   5. A message displays how many items were found that match the criteria. Press “Esc” to close the dialog box or click the “X” in the upper-right corner of the dialog box

All your highlighted sections are selected. Press “Ctrl + C” to copy all the highlighted text, now you can paste it on excel and in excel you need to DATA and text to columns